# Docker ./build.sh: not found при попытке выполнении скопированного скрипта

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Пытаюсь собрать образ из Dockerfile в котором указан скрипт для установки приложения. Сборку выполняю:

```
docker build C:\docker
```

Пример Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:jessie

COPY build.sh ./build.sh

RUN chmod +x ./build.sh
RUN ./build.sh
```

При выполнении "RUN ./build.sh" получаю ошибку

> /bin/sh: 1: ./build.sh: not found
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c ./build.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127

Если перед этой строкой вывести содержимое каталога, то build.sh в нем есть, да и chmod выполняется без ошибки.

Сам скрипт простой:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
apt-get update
```

Что может быть причиной данной ошибки?

Comment: все таки его там нету

Comment: возможно, в build.sh есть утилита, которая отсуствует в образе. покажите что в build.sh

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Дополнил вопрос. Т.к. это мое знакомство с докером, то скрипт невероятно прост. Если в Dockerfile указываю RUN apt-get update то все выполняется

Comment: я у себя выполнил ваш пример. у меня билдится успешно. 
попробуйте файл Dockerfile и build.sh держать рядом. перейти в директорию с Dockerfile и выполнить `docker build -t test .`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Dockerfile и build.sh в одной директории, больше ни чего нет. Выполняю "docker build -t test ." та же ошибка(

Comment: Всего то нужно было изменить формат переноса строки с CRLF на LF и все заработало

Comment: оформите это ответом, пожалуйста. подробно напишите из-за чего и как вы решили